# Is a constraint on function context possible?

Tags: typescript

As an example, say I have this code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public myText: string) {
    }
}

// enforce the context to be of type MyClass for this function
function myFunction() {
    alert(this.myText);
}

var myObject = new MyClass("Hello");
myFunction.call(myObject);              // good
myFunction();                           // bad
```

Is there any way, in TypeScript, to constrain the `this` variable to always be an object of class `MyClass`? That would be useful for cracking down on some bugs at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible in TypeScript 2.0+. You use a `this: Type` annotation as the first argument to the function:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public myText: string) {
    }
}

// enforce the context to be of type MyClass for this function
function myFunction(this: MyClass) {
    alert(this.myText);
}

var myObject = new MyClass("Hello");
myFunction.call(myObject);              // good
myFunction();                           // bad
```

Comment: Thanks and that's too bad. It would be cool to be able to define it like C#'s extension methods: `function myFunction(this myObject: MyClass) { alert(myObject.myText); }`

Comment: It's good this is supported now. `--noImplicitThis` is a useful addition too.

Comment: I'm not a fan of extension methods and other globals. I like when a file is completely understandable by just looking at it on github. All the imports are right there and you know how *any* project *ticks* :)

Comment: Yeah, I share that opinion for javascript, but not c#. Also, I'd never write code like what I show in this question haha. I'll get more use out of `--noImplictThis` pointing out mistakes quickly if it works the way I think it will work. For example: refactoring a class to a function and having it point out all the `this` variables instead of treating it like an `any` type and not throwing a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't pass in the object reference directly to the function rather than rely on the `this` being correct, below is a slightly different approach that you might be able to use in some cases:

```
module Test {
    export class Example {
        Test1(): void { 
           // code here
        }
    }

    export function myFunction():void {
        if (this instanceof Example) {
            var asExample: Example = <Example>this;
            asExample.Test1();
        }   
    }   
}

var ex = new Test.Example();
Test.myFunction.call(ex);
Test.myFunction();
```

By using `instanceof`, you can limit the callers to only objects that are actually instances of `Example` as shown above. You could make it a one liner as well to do a type check and cast:

```
export function myFunction():void {
    var that = assertType<Example>(this, Example);
    that.Test1();
}   

function assertType<T>(obj:any, cls: any): T {
    if (obj instanceof cls ) {
            return <T>obj;
    }
    alert("Type mismatch");
    return null;
    //throw new Error('Type mismatch');
}
```