# Ambient TypeScript functions with specific THIS type

Tags: typescript

How can we declare a function in ambient TypeScript that's called with `this` set to a specific type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a constraint on function context possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519547/is-a-constraint-on-function-context-possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `this: Type` as the first arugument on the function:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public myText: string) {
    }
}

// enforce the context to be of type MyClass for this function
function myFunction(this: MyClass) {
    alert(this.myText);
}

var myObject = new MyClass("Hello");
myFunction.call(myObject);              // good
myFunction();                           // bad
```

Comment: I am using the latest TypeScript 1.8.10, and such `this: MyClass` syntax is not supported. What am I missing?

Comment: You need typescript *nightlies* : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html